# What is a good way to test change of location in AngularJS E2E test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

I have a login form and now i would like to make an integration test to see if user is redirected to the other page after successful login.

Behind the curtains there is authorization service that fires a page reload via  `$window.location.href = 'home';`

First i had this:

```
it('should redirect to /home if credentials are correct', function(){
    browser().navigateTo('/login');
    input('credentials.username').enter('testuser');
    input('credentials.password').enter('testpass');
    element('button.login').click();
    expect(browser().location().path()).toBe("/home");
});
```

but AngularJS test failed both - run as Karma and as runner in browser. Then i thought that maybe `expect` is too soon and i added `sleep(1)` before it. And then it was fine and in test runner I could see the page refresh before assertion.

I assume it might work better if i had location().path('/home') but i prefer full reload at this step.

Is there any design/test pattern that should be used in such cases so i don't have to put sleep() before expected location change?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code;

```
it('should redirect to /home if credentials are correct', function(){
    browser().navigateTo('/login');
    input('credentials.username').enter('testuser');
    input('credentials.password').enter('testpass');
    element('button.login').click();
    browser().navigateTo('/home');
});
```